# precision about structure loading in memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

```
typedef struct sample_s 
{
  int sampleint;
  sample2 b;
} sample;

typedef struct sample2_s
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
} sample2;

int main()
{
  sample t;
}
```

In this example, when I create the instance t of the sample structure, I will also load sample2 in memory.

The Question is, how is it possible to only load the sampleint in the memory ?
Is there a way to only load a part of a structure in memory ? 
If the answer is, like I think it is, the inheritance. How does it work exactly ? Will there be a waste of time during the execution due to hash table ?

I am asking those question because I want to develop a DOD (data oriented design) program and I want to understand better how structures are managed in the memory.

Thank you

Comment: what does 'the heritage' mean? You meant 'traditional' - 'default'?

Comment: I had on mind to erase sample2 b from sample and making the struct sample2 inherit from sample (struct sample2 : public sample) like that by casting an instance of sample from a sample 2 I just have the sampleint stored. But if I do that, I don't know if it optimized (Because in DOD development you have to be careful about heritage and virtual) that's why I ask those question in this post

Comment: my bad! OK! 'heritage'  means inheritance -

Comment: sorry for my frenglish xD; I corrected the miss spelling

Comment: no worries! have you considered storing a pointer to `sample2` in `sample` instead of `sample2` struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to copy sampleint, you can declare `int s = x.sampleint;`  You can also `memcpy()` a range of memory defined by the `offsetof` macro in `<stddef.h>` to get a range of consecutive member variables.

It seems as if what you want is one of the following:

Declare a samplebase type that, in C++, sample can inherit from.

Declare storage for only the individual members you want to copy.

Have sample hold a pointer to a sample2, and set that to NULL if you aren’t allocating one.

Declare the sample as a temporary in a block of code, copy the parts you want, let the memory be reclaimed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: If I do x.sampleint, it doesnt change the fact that b (the sample2) is stored in memory during the declaration of x. It is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I’ve added some more suggestions.